# Linq alternative to retrieving Lookup values by key (or partial key)

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on the following code to find a "description" based on a search phrase that the user will specify. Think of the Keys as important phrases and the Values as a description on where to go to find that phrase.
Think of it as a store locator for example (best analogy I can think up). If you search "Target" (key), you'll get tons of cities (value) and some may have the same name. So there can be multiple Targets in the same city.
A `Dictionary` will obviously not work, because I'll either have duplicate store names, or possibly duplicate city names. Which brings me to my actual situation:

Basically, I'm starting from a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` to allow for duplicates in both directions, then converting that to a `Lookup<string, string>` which I assumed would be less confusing than it is turning out to be.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
Lookup<string, string> collection;

kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K1", "R1"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K1", "R1"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K1", "R2"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K2", "R1"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K2", "R2"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K2", "R3"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("K2", "R1"));

collection = (Lookup<string,string>)kvpList.ToLookup(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
```

The above is simply fake test information, but I feel like there must be a cleaner way to get the results from the `Lookup` especially since it appears to be very Linq-friendly. Unfortunately, I am quite unfamiliar with Linq, and the syntax of Linq itself doesn't seem to lend itself to be very beginner-friendly. I get the results in this code (hard coded search term just for testing purposes):

```
string searchTerm = "K2";
List<string> uniqueResults = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in collection)
{
    if (item.Key.Contains(searchTerm))
    {
        foreach (var value in item)
        {
            if (!uniqueResults.Contains(value))
            {
                uniqueResults.Add(value);
                Console.WriteLine("Added: " + value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Skipped duplicate: " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have issues with the above code, but my **question** is: Is there a way to use Linq to achieve what I am trying to accomplish? I feel like what I have is not the best way this could be done...
It may be worth noting that a partial `searchTerm` **must also be able to find results where it occurs in the key** (hence contains). Existing answers weren't quite able to answer my specific questions. I was not able to find one to help me get values by a partial key search.

Comment: A lookup is like a dictionary, there is no substring search. You can't use a set based approach if you need a substring search because they use `GetHashCode` which can't handle part of strings(how could it return a single value for all substrings?).

Comment: I suggest making "a partial searchTerm must also be able to find results where it occurs in the key" much more prominent in your question, changing the title and making it part of the first few paragraphs. It shapes the question quite a bit I think.

Comment: Thank you @31eee384, made the changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code translated to LINQ would look like this:

```
var uniqueResults = collection
        .Where(item => item.Key.Contains(searchTerm)) // filter the collection
        .SelectMany(x => x)                           // flatten results
        .Distinct()                                   // remove duplicates
        .ToList();
```

You don't even need the `Lookup`. You can get the same results with `kvpList`:

```
var uniqueResults = kvpList
        .Where(item => item.Key.Contains(searchTerm)) // filter the collection
        .Select(item => item.Value)                   // get the Values from KeyValuePairs
        .Distinct()                                   // remove duplicates
        .ToList();
```

The LINQ solution is actually much easier to understand than the imperative one. Try to describe your algorithm in English: From `kvpList`, select distinct values where key contains the search term. That's almost exactly the 2nd LINQ code.

Comment: The lookup is useless here. OP should use only `kvpList`(so replace `collection` with `kvpList`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, and it's even easier to understand than the version with lookup. I included both versions in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @JakubLortz! That makes it much easier to understand the LINQ way to do this. Definitely easier to understand with the context.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the Select and SelectMany were tripping me up more than the rest when I was trying to find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ and a `HashSet<string>`, which would eliminate duplicates for you:

```
var uniqueResults = collection.Where(item => item.Contains(searchTerm))
                              .SelectMany(x => x)
                              .ToHashSet();
```

Where `ToHashSet` is a custom extension method you can create easily:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(enumerable);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing one level of flattening. `uniqueResults` in the question contains the values, not an enumerable of HashSet's.

Comment: @CoderDennis Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: Not *quite* as simple as Jakub's answer, but still very cool! +1 from me.